# Necesito tomar datos de una pagina con scrapy y exportarlos a mysql

Tags: python, scrapy

Buen día.

Necesito tomar datos de la tabla de la pagina http://lanacion.com.ar/econimia/divisas y debo hacerlo con scrapy, buscando información por internet, encontré que no sería la mejor opción scrapy, pero dado que se me pidió desde el trabajo no tengo opción.

Estuve intentando bastante pero ni siquiera logre hacer que el spider toma los datos. Le doy que tome los datos del xpath `//div[@class='fila']` pero cuando termina de correr el spider, nunca devuelve nada, me deja un archivo vacío, sin importar que cambie en el código. Puedo dejar vacío el spider y de igual manera no cambia para el resultado.
No tengo experiencia en scrapy, lo cual seguramente, debe ser gran parte del problema.

Para correrlo estoy usando una maquina virtual sobre Windows 10 para usar Ubuntu y le doy el comando `scrapy crawl miproyecto`.
Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: la url de referencia esta mal escrita, debe ser, https://www.lanacion.com.ar/economia/divisas hay un typo en la escritura

Comment: Puedes subir el codigo de tu spider para revisarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Primero tenemos que seleccionar la forma de obtener la info, yo uso XPath, para los resultados que requerimos que es la tabla de conversion de divisas es:

```
divisas = response.xpath('//*[@id="acumulado"]/section[3]/section[1]/div/div/div')
```

Para poder almacenar los resultados se debe configurar el archivo items.py

```
import scrapy


class DivisasItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    nombre = scrapy.Field()
    ultimo = scrapy.Field()
    anterior = scrapy.Field()
    variacion = scrapy.Field()
    fechahora = scrapy.Field(serializer=str)
    pass
```

Luego en el archivo del spider creado:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from divisas.items import *


class LanacionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lanacion'
    allowed_domains = ['lanacion.com.ar']
    start_urls = ['http://www.lanacion.com.ar/economia/divisas']

    def parse(self, response):
        ##print(response.xpath('//*[@id="acumulado"]/section[3]/section[1]/div/div/div').extract())
        divisas = response.xpath('//*[@id="acumulado"]/section[3]/section[1]/div/div/div')

        items = []

        for divisa in divisas:
            item = DivisasItem()
            print (divisa.xpath('label[1]').extract())
            item['nombre']  = divisa.xpath('label[1]/text()').extract()
            item['ultimo'] = divisa.xpath('label[2]/b/text()').extract()
            item['anterior'] = divisa.xpath('label[3]/text()').extract()
            item['variacion'] = divisa.xpath('label[4]/text()').extract()
            item['fechahora'] = divisa.xpath('label[5]/text()').extract()

            items.append(item)


        ##pass

        return items
```

He subido todos los archivos a mi Git [Spider por Jhovanny Uribe](https://github.com/jjuribe/lanacion/tree/master/divisas)

Corremos el spider

```
scrapy crawl lanacion -o file.csv -t csv
```

**Revisamos que el archivo queda exportado correctamente**

```
cat file.csv
```

anterior,nombre,variacion,ultimo,fechahora

anterior,Descripción,variación,,[u'fecha/hora']

"37,900",Dolar Minorista," -0,53%","37,700",[u'25.10 - 16:56']

"9,936",Real x Pesos," +0,0%","9,937",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

"0,2622",Real x Dolar," +0,0%","0,2636",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

"42,184",Euro x Pesos," -0,8%","41,845",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

"1,1130",Euro x Dolar," -0,8%","1,1099",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

"0,729",Pesos x Peso Mex.,"  0,0%","0,729",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

"0,0192",Peso Mex. x Dolar,"  0,0%","0,0193",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

"0,054",Pesos x Peso Chile," -0,2%","0,054",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

"0,0014",Peso Chile x Dolar," -0,2%","0,0014",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

"0,326",Pesos x Yen," +0,5%","0,328",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

"0,0086",Yen x Dolar," +0,5%","0,0087",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

"47,723",Libras x Peso ," -1,0%","47,242",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

"1,2592",Libra x Dolar," -1,0%","1,2531",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

"2,861",PURU x Pesos,"  0,0%","2,861",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

"0,0755",PURU x Dolar,"  0,0%","0,0759",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

"37,900",Dolar Banco Nacion," -0,5%","37,700",[u'25.10 - 21:16']

La exportacion a la base de datos MySql puede realizarse al final, o durante el proceso usadon **Pipeline**

Comment: debiste esperar a que suba su código y de ahi partir

Comment: Gracias. Intenté correr tu código y no funcionó, de hecho me tiro varios errores. El que mas destaco, es que no encuentra el spider. Intente tanto usando los archivos que ofreciste como copiar a mano el codigo y no funciono.

Comment: Lo invito a clonar este repositorio https://github.com/jjuribe/lanacion/tree/master/divisas

Comment: Luego de clonar ejecute el spider de acuerdo a la respuesta.

Comment: @GonzaloOrtiz pudiste correr el code ?

Comment: @JhovannyUribe si, muchisimas gracias