# Scrapy no encuentra mi spider

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, scrapy

Tengo problemas con Scrapy, por alguna razon cuando corro el proyecto no encuentra mi spider, pero por mas que mire el código no encuentro el porque. Ya había usado un código similar en otra version del código y encontraba el spider.

Dejo el error que me da al correrlo:

```
gonzalo@gonzalo-pc:~/Desktop/lanacion/datos$ scrapy crawl datos -t csv
2018-10-29 14:31:01 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: datos)
2018-10-29 14:31:01 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.6.7rc1 (default, Sep 27 2018, 09:51:25) - [GCC 8.2.0], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0i  14 Aug 2018), cryptography 2.3.1, Platform Linux-4.18.0-10-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.10-cosmic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gonzalo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 69, in load
return self._spiders[spider_name]
KeyError: 'datos'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gonzalo/.local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/gonzalo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in execute
_run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/home/gonzalo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 90, in _run_print_help
func(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/gonzalo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 157, in _run_command
cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/home/gonzalo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/home/gonzalo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 170, in crawl
crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/home/gonzalo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 198, in create_crawler
return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/home/gonzalo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 202, in _create_crawler
spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "/home/gonzalo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 71, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: datos'
```

Si alguie pudiera darme una ayuda estaria muy agradecido. Ya que este error me tiene sin poder avanzar y terminar el problema.
Dejo los codigos de mi Spider, Item y Pipeline:

Spider.py
    import scrapy
    from datos.items import *

```
class DatosSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lanacion'
    allowed_domains = ['lanacion.com.ar']
    start_urls = ['http://www.lanacion.com.ar/economia/divisas']

def parse(self, response):
    ##print(response.xpath('//*[@id="acumulado"]/section[3]/section[1]/div/div/div').extract())
    divisas = response.xpath('//*[@id="acumulado"]/section[3]/section[1]/div/div/div')

    items = []

    for divisa in divisas:
        item = DatosItems()
        print (divisa.xpath('label[1]').extract())
        item['nombre']  = divisa.xpath('label[1]/text()').extract()
        item['ultimo'] = divisa.xpath('label[2]/b/text()').extract()
        item['anterior'] = divisa.xpath('label[3]/text()').extract()
        item['variacion'] = divisa.xpath('label[4]/text()').extract()
        item['fechahora'] = divisa.xpath('label[5]/text()').extract()

        items.append(item)


    ##pass

    return items
```

Item.py

```
import scrapy


class DatosItems(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    # Info de cotización
    descripcion = scrapy.Field()
    ultimo = scrapy.Field()
    anterior = scrapy.Field()
    variacion = scrapy.Field()
    fechahora = scrapy.Field()

pass
```

Pipelines.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
import csv

class DatosPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file ={}

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    pipeline = cls()
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    return pipeline
def spider_opened(self, spider):
    file = open('%s_items.csv' % spider.name, 'w+b')
    self.file[spider] = file
    self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file)
    self.exporter.fields_to_export = ['descripcion', 'ultimo', 'anterior', 'variacion', 'fechahora']
    self.exporter.start_exporting()

def spider_closed(self, spider):
    self.exporter.finish_exporting()
    file = self.file.pop(spider)
    file.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.exporter.expoty_item(item)
    return item
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La razon por la que no encuentra el spider es porque ese no es el nombre del spider, la instruccion para correr el spider es:

```
scrapy crawl Nombre_del_spider
```

Si el spider no se encuentra va a arrojar error.

Ese spider no va a funcionar de la forma como lo esta ejecutando.

```
scrapy crawl datos -t csv
```

La forma adecuada es realizarlo como se lo especifique en la respuesta a su pregunta anterior [Respuesta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207951/necesito-tomar-datos-de-una-pagina-con-scrapy-y-exportarlos-a-mysql)

```
scrapy crawl lanacion -o file.csv -t csv
```

La razon es que el spider no se llama Datos, el nombre es lanacion, git link [Clonar Spider](https://github.com/jjuribe/lanacion)